# issue accessing a text using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find Approvals in the following html and cant seem to get it. I've tried:

1. `//td[*/text()='Approvals']`
2. `//td[contains(@class, 'Approvals')]`

any help would be appreciated

```
<td class="ThemeGrayMainItem" name="cmSubMenuID4" 
    onmouseup="cmItemMouseUp (this,1,'cmSubMenuID4',0,32)"
    onmouseout="cmItemMouseOut (this,1,'cmSubMenuID4',0,32)"
    onmousedown="cmItemMouseDown (this,1,'cmSubMenuID4',0,32)"
    onmouseover="cmItemMouseOverOpenSub (this,1,'cmSubMenuID4',0,32)">Approvals&nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: The HTML seems incomplete, so it's not obvious on *what data* your XPATH expressions work. Especially the first `*` returns some sequence of nodes, and that sequence depends on what is in HTML, which we can see in a small excerpt only, so we can hardly know what is a LHS of comparision to `'Approvals'`...

Answer (score 1):

You may use `contains()`:

```
//td[contains(., 'Approvals')]
```

where `.` refers to the element's text.

You can also apply additional checks, for instance, on the class name:

```
//td[@class='ThemeGrayMainItem' and contains(., 'Approvals')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Approvals')]
```

or if you wanted to be more specific:

```
//td[@class='ThemeGrayMainItem'][contains(text(),'Approvals')]
```